# How to add bootstrap forms in angular 2 with validation support?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, package, angular2-forms

I have tried to create the form like given in below link:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

In above link please took look under the bootstrap topic.

I have imported the forms as like below code example

```
   import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
   import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

   bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms(),
   provideForms()
   ])
```

but the webpage throws 404 found issue in a page while importing the forms.

```
 http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js 

 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

  http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.umd.js Failed to    load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using angular 1.0.0 rc.1 update. Can you please anyone suggest to use these new forms, bootstrap with my current version since upgrading to another version may take more changes with my application.

Comment: Update to RC4 version.

Comment: I want to use with my current version is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked more. But the only solution is updating to RC4 version since the forms support given only from rc2. So i have upgraded my application
Thanks